# Handling asyncio CancelledError simultaneous

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Imagine the following python code to cancel a subtask.
It is not a real program, but should demonstrate the structure.

```py
import asyncio

async def subtask():
    sleep = 99999
    while True:
        try:
            print("Very long task")
            await asyncio.sleep(sleep)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print("Incorrectly caught error")
            sleep = 2  # make it visible that task is still running
            pass

async def handling1():
    for i in range(3):
        print("Start subtask")
        task = asyncio.create_task(subtask())
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        task.cancel()
        print("Subtask canceled")

async def handling2():
    for i in range(3):
        print("Start subtask")
        task = asyncio.create_task(subtask())
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        task.cancel()
        try:
            await task
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            pass
        print("Subtask canceled")


asyncio.run(handling1())
```

Replace `asyncio.run(handling1())` with `asyncio.run(handling2())` to see the other handling.

handling1:

- When subtask it catching the CancelledError it will run forever and cause a memory leak.

  - It is not obvious in a larger project which task caused this.

handling2:

- It will be obvious that subtask was not canceled through the `await task`
- But it can happen that at the same time of calling `await task`, the task `handling2` itself was canceled too.
  So `handling2` will itself catch the `CancelledError`.

  - It is really rare, but it happend in my larger project. (hard to debug)

So is there another way to handle canceling tasks and wait for their end?
(`subtask` is not a real example, but should demonstrate a wrongly caught `CancelledError`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is of course in `subtask`, it should be cancelled when you call `.cancel()` on it.

Since you already know that, said it's incorrectly caught, and know that `handling1` is the correct solution but does not accommodate for the bug, here is a fix to `handling2`:

```
task = asyncio.create_task(subtask())
await asyncio.sleep(1)
task.cancel()
try:
    # Shield will make sure 2nd cancellation from wait_for will not block.
    await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.shield(task), 1)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    if task.cancelled():  # Slight chance of happening
        return # Task was cancelled correctly after exactly 1 second.
    print("Task was not cancelled after 1 second! bug bug bug")
except asyncio.CancelledError:
    if task.cancelled():
        return  # Task was cancelled correctly
    print("handling 2 was cancelled!")
    raise
```

Comment: So the idea is to add a timeout to await a subtask. That makes sense and would be possible.  
But there is no other mechanism to cancel and await another subtask, but not catch the own CanceledError right?

Comment: There is, you can use `asyncio.wait()` to wait for it, then check the task separately. I think a timeout is more appropriate though. (You can use a timeout with wait too, maybe it'll even be easier)

Comment: I opened another thread to demonstrate the canceling a little bit better. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71485532/python-asyncio-race-condition-for-canceling-tasks. But thanks for your idea to catch a stuck task by a timeout error.