# Python asyncio: Race condition for canceling tasks

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I the python examples (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel), a task can be canceled like in the following snippet:

```py
task.cancel()
try:
   await task
except asyncio.CancelledError:
   print("main(): cancel_me is cancelled now")
```

But this can cause a race condition when the task itself is canceled at the same time as canceling the other task.
I have added an example which causes this problem by one addition await statement `await asyncio.sleep(0)`

```
import asyncio


async def subtask(i: int):
    try:
        print(f"        subtask {i}: start")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print(f"        subtask {i}: Clean Up")
        raise


async def handling():
    i = 0
    while True:
        print(f"    handling {i}: start")
        sub_task = asyncio.create_task(subtask(i))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(f"    handling {i}: cancel subtask")
        sub_task.cancel()  # (1) There is a reason why subtask must be canceled, but another must be restarted.
        try:
            await sub_task  # (2)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print(f"    handling {i}: subtask canceled {sub_task.cancelled()}")
        print(f"    handling {i}: end")
        i += 1


async def main():
    print("main: start")
    handling_task = asyncio.create_task(handling())
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await asyncio.sleep(0)  # (3) This addition await call forces that handling_task is cancel at the same as calling (2)
    print("main: cancel")
    handling_task.cancel()  # handling_task must be canceled by a reason at the same time as the other task was canceled by a reason (1)
    try:
        await handling_task
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print(f"main: CancelledError. Task canceled {handling_task.cancelled()}.")
        pass  # Task was cancelled correctly
    print("main: end")


asyncio.run(main())
```

So my guess is, it is never allowed to to catch a CancelledError of a canceled task?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  If task1 wants to cancel task2, but task1 gets cancelled before it has a chance to do that, then task2 isn't cancelled.  Welcome to multithreading.  You need to plan for this.

Comment: The problem is that the function `handling` is not catching the CancelledError of sub_task, it is catching the own CancelledError of `main`. So there is now way to differentiate between those two exceptions.

Comment: @NINI1988 not sure if there's a way to differentiate, both tasks cancel at the same position.